# Redux Async actions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to setup an action so that when I make an AJAX call I can then fire off another action that updates the state with the data that is returned from the call:

**actions.js**

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const setUserTeamsState = (teams) => {
    return {
        type:'SET_USER_TEAMS',
        teams:teams
    }
}


export const getUserTeams = (dispatch) => {

    return axios.get('http://localhost:7777/getteams')
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response.data)
                dispatch(setUserTeamsState(response.data))
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                //console.log(error);
            });     
}
```

in my component I call the action like so:

```
this.props.teamActions.getUserTeams()
```

The `getUserTeams` action fires off fine because I get the console log returned from the api but the `setUserTeamsState` one doesn't seem to. I've tried to follow online examples as best I can but not sure where i#ve gone wrong?

**EDIT**

Here is my reducer below:

**Reducer.js**

```
const initialState = {
  userTeams: []
};

const manageTeamsReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SET_USER_TEAMS': {
      const newState = Object.assign(state, {
        userTeams:action.teams
      });
      return newState;
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default manageTeamsReducer;
```

if in actions.js I `console.log(dispatch(setUserTeamsState(response.data)))` it returns my the `setUserTeamsState` object so i'm not sure why it's not executing. Is this the correct approach to begin with?

Comment: Do you see any errors on console? Are you getting any type of exception?

Comment: Is your reducer getting called when `SET_USER_TEAMS` is dispatched?

Comment: It looks like you're setting userTeams as an array in initial State, but returning and Object as new state in the reducer call....

Comment: highly recommend using thunks for Redux async actions:
https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk

Answer (score 0):

If the console.log shows you correct value, I believe that you might have forgotten to add your reducer or type of action doesnt match any types known to your reducers. The solution to those typos is to keep all types in separate file and just export them like:

(actions/types.js)

`export const SET_USER_TEAMS = 'SET_USER_TEAMS';`

Then just import them in reducer and in your action.

If that's not a typo then you should check if the reducer is dispatched at all. If it is there's some bug in your reducer.

Comment: posted my reducer above, all looks in order

Comment: is the reducer executed at all? can you see it logging action? (after adding console.log(action); )

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
const manageTeamsReducer = (state = initialState.userTeams, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SET_USER_TEAMS':
      return [
    action.teams
  ];
    break;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

This is assuming you action.teams is an array of team objects...

try this in your action as well:

```
export const getUserTeams = () => (dispatch) => {

    return axios.get('http://localhost:7777/getteams')
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response.data)
                dispatch(setUserTeamsState(response.data))
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                //console.log(error);
            });     
}
```

Comment: refresh - added initialState.userTeams instead of just initialState

Comment: That's now crashed the app

Comment: Ok just comment out the return - and console.log(action) under that case 'SET_USER_TEAMS: and make sure its getting the correct action....

Comment: I also added another update to the answer including a new action for you to try. You do have Thunk Middleware installed right?

Comment: so I basically log every time the state updates and my first states before I fire off the one in this question are all logging the reducer type that's fired but for this one nothing is logged which leads me to believe that it's never firing due to the way the action has been setup, im not sure where though!

Comment: yes I have thunk installed, I tried your amend to my action and still nothing

Comment: If the action isn't getting called at all - I would make sure you are dispatching the action correctly from the component. What does the component look like?

Comment: the component fires this off: this.props.teamActions.getUserTeams(). I'm pretty sure this one is firing off correctly as I am getting the console.log(response.data) from the first function

Comment: even if I put a console.log in the setUserTeamsState function it logs that meaning it reaches there but for some reason does not dispatch properly

Comment: yep, its definitely in there

Comment: If you remove the call to axios - and just return and dispatch a fake array with an object inside it calling setUserTeamState, does the reducer get called?

Comment: Also can you confirm the reducer is being called at all by putting a console.log outside of the case and just under the switch to make sure its being called...

Comment: I can't do that because i'm using this in a chrome extension and I can't exactly console log in reducers. Returning a fake array doesn't help

Comment: well it seems like the issue is with the reducer because both actions seem to get fired. Can you install redux-devtools-extension or something to make sure the reducer is getting called correclty?

Comment: it's not because if I fire off this.props.teamActions.setUserTeamsState([{_id: "123", name: "some name"}]) then it works as it should

Comment: Then its an async issue